# Remote Desktop Licensing took over my base RDP function

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

My remote desktop capability is currently being held random by the remote desktop licensing feature in Server 2012.

On my server I installed the "remote desktop licensing services" feature/role and everything underneath it with the intent of configuring it one day just so that I could say "I did it". However, the time to configure it expired and I completely forgot that it would disable remote desktop access to the server and now I don't know what to do. I don't have a license server configured on the server which I assume is what I need to do but is there a simpler or easier way for me to just avoid having to mess with remote desktop licensing at all so I can just start remoting back into my server from my other machines at home?

Please advise on the path of least resistance.

Comment: If you're not using the RDS role then uninstall that role and uninstall the RDS License role. You'll then be allowed 2 RDS sessions for administrative purposes with no RDS licenses required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path of least resistance  would be to uninstall the Remote Desktop service role. If you are not using the server as a session host, you could do with the 2 administrative sessions. No additional licensing or configuration needed.